# find difference between times in c

Tags: c, datetime, time

I have 2 time strings and want to find difference between them. My code works. But it shows different outputs when i try same values. Here's my code:

```
    #include <time.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    time_t convtotime(char *time_detail,char *format){
        struct tm tm;
        strptime(time_detail,format,&tm);
        time_t t = mktime(&tm);
        return t;

    }
    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {
        char buff[25];
        time_t newtime = convtotime("12/Dec/2014:10:44:19","%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S");
        time_t oldtime = convtotime("12/Dec/2014:10:44:35","%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S");
        printf("%lf",difftime(oldtime,newtime));
    }
```

And it outputs:

```
3616.000000
```

or

```
16.000000
```

Comment: Do you mean you get different results when running this exact program again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual for strptime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) says:

> In principle, this function does not initialize tm but stores only
>   the values specified. **This means that tm should be initialized before
>   the call**.

So try:

```
struct tm tm = {0};
strptime(time_detail, format, &tm);
```

The wording in [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html) is also interesting:

> It is unspecified whether multiple calls to strptime() using the same
>   tm structure will update the current contents of the structure or
>   overwrite all contents of the structure.

Comment: So the observed One Hour offset was due to the Daylight Saving member of `tm` containing some random value. Good catch!